# When I create shortcut (B) to another shortcut (A) its taking path of Shortcut A

Tags: winapi

I have created Shortcut A which has the target path to `"C:\firefox.exe" -P "profile one" -no-remote`

I then create a desktop shortcut (Shortcut B) pointing to this Shortcut A. However the path in the shortcut i (even though i told it to `shellLink.SetPath` to the path of Shortcut A) is set to the target of of Shortcut A.

Defeating my purpose. Because I change the command line arguments or target path of Shortcut A depending on if user settings. But I want the desktop shortcut (Shortcut B) to not need modification as it will be pointing to Shortcut A. Reason I want this is because I initially create shortcut B on desktop for user, but user may move that to another folder, so I can't find that and update its build path etc. Whereas Shortcut A is kept in one of my folders which I always know the path to.

So is there a way to ensure the target path of Shortcut B is the location path of Shortcut A (rather then the target path of Shortcut A)

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this a question for [su]?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  You can't, for example, pass command-line arguments to shortcut files themselves.  Also note that if you try to manually create a shortcut to a shortcut (e.g. by pasting the path to a `.lnk` file into the Target field), you will get an error message "You can't create a shortcut to another shortcut. Either copy the shortcut and place it in the new location, or create a new shortcut to the original file or folder."

Comment: Thanks @james would hard link/junction be more suited? I'm just learning about those.

Comment: @Noitidart: try it and see.

Comment: Thanks @Sam i struggled with it but finally figured it out, i was creating the hard link in the same directory so it kept creating a blank file. I changed directory and it works! and just like i hoped!! update to icon propogates to other, update to target propagates, but update of file name does not, very sweet. thank you!

Comment: Good job.  Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what I wrote in an earlier comment, apparently creating a shortcut to a shortcut *is* programmatically possible starting in Windows 7 by using [the `SLDF_ALLOW_LINK_TO_LINK` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762540.aspx) with `IShellLinkDataList::SetFlags`.

Comment: Thanks you @james! I actually needed to support XP and Vista so I ended up making hard links to a shortcut. But thanks very much for this reply.

Answer (score 0):

I used [`CreateHardLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860.aspx):

Update to icon propogates to other, update to target propagates, but update of file name does not, very sweet. thank you!

Apparently `CreateSymbolicLink` needed elevated privelages so I tried hard link and it worked, but required me the hardlink to be in another directory then the target file.